# How can I exclude Foreign Entities when calling GetProperties on an Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

```
var properties = person.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                                    BindingFlags.Public |
                                                    BindingFlags.Instance);
```

The above returns `Car` and `CarReference` as part of the properties, but these are foreign entities to `Person`.  I want to exclude them from `GetProperties`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "Foreign Entities?" Can you provide an example?

Comment: @Romoku - In my database, Car has a Foriegn key to Person, so when I create my Model, it creates a CarReference.

Comment: You are mixing reflection and entity framework specific attributes here. If you want to solve this by using reflection only, you can check `PropertyType` of the properties and implement some convention yourself.

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg - What would be the PropertyType for Foreign Entities?

Comment: Since you are in control there, it's up to you. Maybe the entities share a common base class? If not, maybe they share namespace?

Comment: @MikaelÖstberg - When I say Entity, I mean Entities generated by the entity framework

Answer (score 0):

`EntityFramework` `POCO`s are designed to be difficult to work out what is an association. This is because all the information is in `Entity Framework`, and none of that information is in the `POCO` (kind of the point of POCO). You would have to get into the EDM classes in EF.

You can access the EDM I think... via

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
var metadata = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
```

But that's the best I can do for you...

Answer (score 0):

Well, a rustic solution, but it may be enough for your needs.

Just exclude properties which are class (this will exclude the single navigation properties) and the generic type (this will exclude the collection properties, for example an `ICollection<Person>` in `Car`)

```
var properties = typeof(Items).GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(m => !m.PropertyType.IsClass && 
                            !m.PropertyType.IsGenericType);
```

Comment: If I need to exclude properties, I probably need to add those to some exclusion list or add them to the where clause, right?

Comment: "Just exclude properties which are class" this will exclude any String properties, not just the navigation properties !!